# How to get the model defined in child's form on parent button click?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-include, ng-controller

**Parent.html**

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">

<div ng-include="'views/Child.html'">
</div>

<button ng-click="GetChildModel()">
</button>   

</div>
```

**Child.html**

```
<form ng-controller="childcontroller">
<input type="text" ng-model="child.Firstname">
</input>
 <input type="text" ng-model="child.Lastname">
</input>
</form>
```

*My problem is that i need the model defined in child.html into my parent controller i.e parentController
How it can be possible?*

Answer (score 0):

Forms can be a controller if you add the "name" attribute

```
<form name="child">
<input type="text" name="Firstname">
</form>
```

You can access in parent controller with: $scope.child.Firstname

Answer (score 0):

In your parent controller:

```
$scope.child = {};
$scope.GetChildModel = function() {
    console.log(angular.toJson($scope.child));
}
```